# Question about the proof : Dedekind completeness of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> *Having trouble understanding the second step of the argument, when proving that all bounded subsets of real numbers have a least upper bound. Came across it in Pugh's analysis **page 14***

---

**Theorem.** The set $\mathbb{R}$ constructed by means of Dedekind cuts, is **complete** in the sense that it satisfies the least upper bound property:

"Every non-empty subset of real numbers that is bounded above has a least upper bound".

---

*Proof.*
Let $\mathcal{C\subset \mathbb{R}}$ be any non-empty collection of cuts which is bounded above, say by the cut $X | Y$. Define,

$C:=\{a \in \mathbb{Q}:\text{ for some cut } A|B \text{ we have } a\in A\}$ and $D=\text{rest of }\mathbb{Q}$

It is easy to see that $z:=C|D$ is a cut. Clearly, it is an upper bound for $\mathcal{C}$, since $A$-set for every element of $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset of $C$. Hence, $x \le z$ for all $x \in \mathcal{C}$.

We are interested to prove that $z=C|D$ is the least upper bound for the set $\mathcal{C}$. Let $z'=C'|D'$ be any upper bound of $\mathcal{C}$. By the assumption that, $A|B \le C'|D'$ for all $A|B \in \mathcal{C}$, we see that the $A$ for every member of $\mathcal{C}$ is contained in $C'$.

> I have a doubt here. In the argument that follows, how does the author automatically assume, that $C \subset C'$? Does it follow from the fact, that we do not explicitly define $C'$? My reasoning is, we are only aware that $A \subset C'$ for all $A|B$, so $C'$ can contain the $A$-sets and whole lot more than that. Hence, $C \subset C'$.

Hence, $C \subset C'$. So, $z \le z'$ for all $z'$'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $C \subset C'$, note that by definition, $C =\{a \in A : A|B \in \mathcal C\} = \bigcup_{A|B\in\mathcal C}A$.

Because $C'|D'$ is an upper bound for $\mathcal C$, for all $A|B \in \mathcal C, A|B \le C'|D'$, which means $A \subset C'$.

If $a \in C$, then there is some $A|B \in \mathcal C$ with $a \in A$. But $A \subset C'$, so $a \in C'$. Hence $C \subset C'$.